# Sql(Oracle) select statement doesn't fetch all rows

Tags: sql, oracle, select

I have simple SQL select query. However it doesn't fetch all results. For example there are 3 rows that have same value '16T00423'.

`select * from a table t where t.column = '16T00423'` returns 2 results.

`select * from a table t where t.column like '%16T00423%'` returns 2 results.

`select * from a table t where t.column like '%00423%'` returns all 3 three results.

DB is Oracle. What is the problem? pls help.

Comment: `like` without a wildcard is the same as `=`

Comment: Like but no wildcards? Why?

Comment: Try to add percent symbols before and after like this:
select * from a table t where t.column like '%00423%'

Comment: If you're really already querying with wildcards and don't see the results you expect, do you have extra whitespace in one of the values?

Comment: sorry for wrong post, but i have used it actually

Comment: no there is not any whitespace

Comment: I tried to compose a fiddle with your code, then realised it's nothing but pseudo-code that can hardly illustrate anything. Sorry but can't get proper help about SQL syntax with vague descriptions of code.

Comment: guys it was probably white space, cuz it worked after i edited that row. Thank you all.

Answer (score 1):

The problem wasn't white space.It was the letter inside of '16T00423', it was entered from russian keyboard, but I use english.